# SQL Server 2012 - assistance with self join or CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

DBMS: SQL Server 2012

I have a table with the following columns

[image]

What I need to be able to do is figure out the `NextCarDepartureTime`. So for example, Car2 would depart at 9/30/2014 1:12 AM, Car3 would depart at 10/1/2014 12:10 AM. The ultimate goal is to figure out the difference in hours between `CarDepartedDateTime` and `NextCarDepartedTime`. So the end result would look like

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You can use the `DateDiff()` function to get the difference in hour.

Comment: I can't see your picture but from the vague description you could use DATEDIFF. Not sure if you want whole number or partial hours so you might need to get the diff in minutes and then divide by 60.0 to get decimal places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`LEAD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) analytic function introduced in SQL server 2012. This function access subsequent row from your table. So your query now look like this -

```
;WITH    myCTE
    AS ( SELECT   T1.Year ,
                T1.Month ,
                T1.CarNumberID ,
                T1.CarDepartedDateTime ,
                T1.CarDepartedNumberID ,
                LEAD(T1.CarDepartedDateTime) OVER ( ORDER BY T1.id ) AS [NextCarDepartureTime] ,
                LEAD(T1.CarNumberID) OVER ( ORDER BY T1.id ) AS [NextCarNumberID]
        FROM     Test T1
        )
SELECT  * ,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, CarDepartedDateTime, NextCarDepartureTime) AS TurnAroundTime
FROM    myCTE;
```

I have written one blog post for analytic function in my blog here : [krishnrajrana.wordpress.com](https://krishnrajrana.wordpress.com/2015/12/04/getting-started-with-analytic-functions-in-sql-server-2012-part-1/)

Answer (score 2):

This would be the basic syntax you would need:

```
SELECT
T1.Year, T1.Month, T1.CarNumberID, T1.CarDepartedDateTime, T1.NextCarNumberID,
T2.CarDepartedDateTime as [NextCarDepartureTime],
CONVERT(varchar,(T2.CarDepartedDateTime - T1.CarDepartedDateTime, 108) as [Turn Around Time]

FROM
DatabaseName..TableName T1
Left outer join DatabaseName..TableName T2 on T2.CarNumberID = T1.NextCarNumberID
```

Depending on other details in the table (Primary Keys, etc.) you may want to add details to the join filters and/or a `WHERE` clause.

There are various options available for how you want to format/display the `[Turn Around Time]` field using different values for the last parameter of the `CONVERT` function. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx for a list of different options.

Comment: my first shot at this was what you suggested. However I returning all of the departure times for the NextCarNumber. So, I believe I need to figure out what I am missing in the join as an additional condition.

Comment: I take it you have multiple departure times for each `CarNumberID` then? If that is the case then you will either need to include a subquery that uses `select top 1` and an `order by` clause to return only the next one record for each row. Alternatively, if they are ordered correctly in the main query then you may be able to use `LEAD` or `LAG` as @KrishnrajRana suggests.

Comment: If you post an example of your existing code and the (incorrect) results you are currently getting it will be easier for us to see what can be modified to get the results you want.

Comment: After making some small adjustments, it looks like Krishnraj's code works using the LEAD function. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: @KrishnrajRana After looking closer, I realized the original data at the beginning of the post is not completely accurate. The NextCarID is not necessarily sequential. So for CarID 1 the NextCarID could be 8. For CarID 2 the NextCarID could be 4.
How would that change your code?